# Count occurance of a string and sum the next comma value from a large file

Tags: unix, csv, grep

I have a large data file that have comma delimited values. e.g.

> Name1, Score1, Name2, Score2, Name3, Score3 
>   Joe, .5, Sam, .2, Bob, .1
>   Bob, .3, Joe, .1
>   Joe, .5

Is there a simple grep command that can return the number of occurrence of each name and the sum of the scores?

I have tried the following to get the count but not sure how i can get the sum of the scores.

> grep string "file" | wc -1

e.g

Expected results:

> Joe, 3, 1.1
>   Sam, 1, .2
>   Bob, 2, .4

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file.txt:

```
Name1, Score1, Name2, Score2, Name3, Score3
Joe, .5, Sam, .2, Bob, .1
Bob, .3, Joe, .1
Joe, .5
```

```
grep -oP '[\w][\w ]*, [0-9.]+' file.txt | awk -F, '{a[$1]+=$2; c[$1]++} END {for(i in a){print i", "c[i]", "a[i]}}'
```

Output:

```
Sam, 1, 0.2
Joe, 3, 1.1
Bob, 2, 0.4
```